# Is it possible to make Spider-Man like web fluid?

Tags: materials, applied-chemistry, chemistry-in-fiction

Is it possible to make a substance which has similar properties to that of the web fluid e.g. High tensile strength, sticky (can attach to most of the surfaces), evaporates within few hours etc. If so then how?

Comment: What *are* the properties of the said "web fluid"? 8D

Comment: I suspect it is the same fluid used in [GITS SAC S01E02 "Testation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ghost_in_the_Shell:_Stand_Alone_Complex_episodes) in order to stop the tank when major Kusanagi failed to open the tank's hatch. I think this is a decent question.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is broad. The OP isn't asking *how* to do it, he is asking if it's **possible** to do it.

Comment: There was similar question [on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-make-spider-mans-web-shooters-web-fluid)

Comment: https://www.wired.com/2014/04/the-physics-of-spider-mans-webs/

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Yes, OP is asking *how*, in the last sentence.